# Telerik Open access Audit Trail

Tags: c#, audit-trail, telerik-open-access

How can i best implement an audit trail for an application that uses Telerik open access. I have posted this question on their support but there has been no reply for days (sucks)
I have already tried the Tracking events within each scope but am unable to save the field that contain List or class attributes. (open access does not support the object datatype)
Example of the class am trying to implement an audit trail for is

```
class myCompany
{
    private int _id;
    private IList<Bus> _myBusses=new List<bus>();
    private User _createdBy;
}
```

Plesase Help

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hook into any changes to the data (see [Tracking Context Changes](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/feature-ref-api-context-api-tracking-context-changes.html))? You could have some helper methods you pass the old & new data to that, then they add the necessary information to the audit log.

Also, these links might be useful too:

- [Getting Changes that Will be Performed During the Next Commit](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/feature-ref-api-context-api-getting-changes.html)
- [Accessing Original Values After Changes](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/feature-ref-api-context-api-access-original-values.html)